# Python: Get Average values from multiple columns in multiple files

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program which will take as input one or more files and summarize the average values coming from 2 columns in each file.

for example I have 2 files:

File1:

```
ID    Feature    Total    Percent
1.2    ABC    300    75
1.4    CDE    129    68
```

File2:

```
ID    Feature   Total    Percent
1.2    ABC    289    34
1.4    CDE    56    94
```

I want to iterate over each file and convert the percent to a number using:

```
def ReadFile(File):
    LineCount = 0
    f = open(File)
    Header =  f.readline()
    Lines = f.readlines()
    for Line in Lines:
        Info = Line.strip("\n").split("\t")
        ID, Feature, Total, Percent= Info[0], Info[1], int(Info[2]), int(Info[3])
        Num = (Percent/100.0)*Total
```

I'm not sure what's the best way to store the output so that I have the ID, Feature, Total and Percent for each file. Ultimately, I would like to create an outfile that contains the average percent over all files. In the above example I would get:

```
ID    Feature    AveragePercent
1.2    ABC    54.9    #(((75/100.0)*300)+((34/100.0)*289)) / (300+289))
1.4    CDE    75.9    #(((68/100.0)*129)+((94/100.0)*56)) / (129+56))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to store some data across reading the files. Say you have a list of file paths in a variable called `files`

```
data = {}
for filepath in files:
  f = open(filepath, "r")
  f.readline()
  for line in f.readlines():
    info = line.strip().split("\t")
    id, feature, total, percent = info[0], info[1], int(info[2]), int(info[3])
    if id in data:
      data[id].total += total * (percent / 100.0)
      data[id].count += total
    else:
      data[id] = {"feature": feature, "total": total * (percent / 100.0), "count": total}

# Output
out = open("outfile", "w")
out.write("ID\tFeature\tAveragePercentage")
for id in data:
  out.write(str(id) + "\t" + data.feature + "\t" + str(data.total / data.count) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 3):

`Pandas` module is the way to go. Assuming that your files are named `'1.txt'` and `'2.txt'`, the following code will store all your input, output, and intermediate computations in pandas' `DataFrame` instance `df`. Additionally, the information of interest will be printed to the file `'out.txt'`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file_names = ['1.txt', '2.txt']
df = None

for f_name in file_names:
    df_tmp = pd.read_csv(f_name, sep = '\t') 
    df = df_tmp if df is None else pd.concat([df,df_tmp])

df['Absolute'] = df['Percent'] * df['Total'] 
df['Sum_Total'] = df.groupby('Feature')['Total'].transform(np.sum)
df['Sum_Absolute'] = df.groupby('Feature')['Absolute'].transform(np.sum)
df['AveragePercent'] =  df['Sum_Absolute'] / df['Sum_Total'] 

df_out = df[['ID','Feature','AveragePercent']].drop_duplicates()

df_out.to_csv('out.txt', sep = "\t", index = False)
```

Comment: just beat me to it! +1

Comment: @ojy - This sounds like a really great solution. Unfortunately I failed to mention that my actual files each contain over 1 million rows of data. When I try to run using the above solution it is exceedingly slow - been running for over an hour...

Comment: @user2165857, do you have an option to use a database instead of a file?

Comment: @user3885927 - I actually am writing to a database (I wrote file for simplicity), but that isn't the bottleneck step.

Comment: Which step in my code was slow? I just tried to simulate 10 mln records, and it took just a couple of seconds to run. How many distinct Feature values do you have approximately? (I made simulation with just 5)

Comment: @ojy - I have about 300,000 - 1,000,000 records for every table I'm trying to create and 5 features. I get stuck at any calculations - in this case it would be df['Absolute'] = df['Percent'] * df['Total'].

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary will be perfect for this.(I've left the header handling part for you)

```
import fileinput

data = {}
for line in fileinput.input(['file1', 'file2']):
    idx, ft, values = line.split(None, 2)
    key = idx, ft     #use ID, Feature tuple as a key.
    tot, per = map(int, values.split())
    if key not in data:
        data[key] = {'num': 0, 'den': 0}
    data[key]['num'] += (per/100.0) * tot
    data[key]['den'] += tot
```

Now `data` contains:

```
{('1.2', 'ABC'): {'num': 323.26, 'den': 589},
 ('1.4', 'CDE'): {'num': 140.36, 'den': 185}}
```

Now we can loop over this dict and calculate the desired result:

```
for (idx, ft), v in data.items():
    print idx, ft, round(v['num']/v['den']*100, 1)
```

**Output:**

```
1.2 ABC 54.9
1.4 CDE 75.9
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this using files with ID, Feature, Total, Percent deliminated with tabs (like your input file) and works great, giving output you want:

```
globalResultsFromReadDictionary = {}

def ReadFile(File):
    LineCount = 0
    f = open(File)
    Header =  f.readline()
    Lines = f.readlines()
    for Line in Lines:
        Info = Line.strip("\n").split("\t")
        ID, Feature, Total, Percent = Info[0], Info[1], int(Info[2]), int(Info[3])

        #Adding to dictionary
        key = ID + "\t" + Feature
        if(key in globalResultsFromReadDictionary):
            globalResultsFromReadDictionary[key].append([Total, Percent])
        else:
            globalResultsFromReadDictionary[key] = [[Total, Percent]]

def createFinalReport(File):
    overallReportFile = open(File, 'w'); #the file to write the report to

    overallReportFile.write('ID\tFeature\tAvg%\n') #writing the header

    for idFeatureCombinationKey in globalResultsFromReadDictionary:

        #Tallying up the total and sum of percent*total for each element of the Id-Feature combination
        sumOfTotals = 0
        sumOfPortionOfTotals = 0
        for totalPercentCombination in globalResultsFromReadDictionary[idFeatureCombinationKey]:
            sumOfTotals += totalPercentCombination[0]
            sumOfPortionOfTotals += (totalPercentCombination[0]*(totalPercentCombination[1]/100))

        #Write to the line (idFeatureCombinationKey is 'ID \t Feature', so can just write that)
        overallReportFile.write(idFeatureCombinationKey + '\t' + str(round((sumOfPortionOfTotals/sumOfTotals)*100, 1)) + '\n')

    overallReportFile.close()

#Calling the functions
ReadFile('File1.txt');
ReadFile('File2.txt');
createFinalReport('dd.txt');
```